# Java- Assigning finished thread objects to new threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Ok, the wording of the title is a bit odd but I didn't really know how to express it. Basically, from what I understand about Java and threads is you make a thread, it runs, it dies. However, the thread OBJECT is still there. What I want to know if something like this is valid

```
int numWorkers = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int threadPoolSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
ExecutorService tpes = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
WorkerThread[] workers = new WorkerThread[numWorkers];
while(some condition)    
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        workers[i] = new WorkerThread(i, *some changing parameters*);
        tpes.execute(workers[i]);
    }
```

Basically what this situation is that we have some condition that we don't know when it will be satisfied. Let's say I'm using 8 threads. I create all 8 threads, they do their thing and return. I put their results together and realize I'm not done yet. However, for example, workers[0] already exists. I created it with a new WorkerThread() call. But it's dead now since it's done running. If I were to call, AGAIN, workers[0] = new WorkerThread(0, *new parameter*)...is that allowed? I need more threads, I have an array already of (now) dead threads...can I just point them at something else? Do the old threads get properly collected by the GC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first: you don't submit **threads** to the Executor Service. You submit **tasks**, which are just objects implementing `run`. The Executor Service is in full control of the thread pool.

You can easily schedule the same `Runnable` any number of times and each time you'll receive another `FutureTask` object that tells you whether it's done and allows you to cancel it. These `FutureTask` objects are not reusable, but that's no problem.

Comment: +1 Sometimes I wonder from where to start and what to put in the answer.

Comment: @amitD I know the feeling :) Many times one needs to just zoom out of the literal text of the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. My understanding of Executors is shaky since I literally just learned about them yesterday. But in that case, the Executor is in charge of actually creating and managing the threads then? I just have to specify what the thread is supposed to do each time?

Comment: I think why I was confused was because and Executor calls execute(some thread). You have to pass it a thread (or something extended runnable) so I thought you were actually submitting threads. If that's not the case, I guess in this case it works. I have 8 threads running, but I don't know how many tasks I'll end up submitting, but even if I submit more, they just kind of wait until a thread is free to run them. Is that understanding a bit closer to what actually happens?

Comment: I see you are confused about the distinction between a `Thread` and a `Runnable`. `Runnable` is just a trivial interface declaring a single `void run()` method, whereas `Thread` is a heavyweight object that manages a system resource (a thread of execution). If you happen to pass in an instance of `Thread` to the ExecutorService, it will still have nothing to do with the actual thread of execution this object manages: ExecutorService will just see the `run` method, and it will invoke it **on one of its own threads**.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That helps clarify a lot of things